# Managing devices on iTunes Store

Tags: itunes, ipad, ios-appstore, facetime

I have bought an iPad 2 a few days ago, have configured it but I am unable to use FaceTime or iMessages. After searching a while, I found this page (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4627). It says how I can manage my devices on iTunes Store but when I follow the steps and visit my account I don't see the MANAGE DEVICES item I should. Apparently the problem I am having is that my iPad is not associated with my Apple ID. The iPad is a brand new, bought on a store.

How do I associate this new iPad with my apple ID?

Another problem is this: if I try to flick the switches for automatic downloads of apps and books the same switches flick to off half second later.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've correctly set your Apple ID in the Settings section, for both Facetime and Messages applications, in your iPad.